# Building SSIS 2014 Project deployment model from cmd line

Tags: sql-server, deployment, ssis, sql-server-2014, ssis-2014

Build SSIS 2014 Solution/project from cmd line is not working
Used several scripts with no luck.

```
C:\Users\Source\Repos\ETL "C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2017\Enterprise\Common7\IDE\devenv.exe" 
\ETL.sln /build "Development|Default"
```

Different variations of this script does not work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try using `Debug` instead of `"Development|Default"`:

```
C:\Users\Source\Repos\ETL> "C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2017\Enterprise\Common7\IDE\devenv.exe" 
"ETL.sln" /build Debug
```

You can simply use devenv without specifying the full path:

```
C:\Users\Source\Repos\ETL> devenv "ETL.sln" /build Debug
```

Also try passing the solution full path as argument:

```
C:\Users\Source\Repos\ETL> devenv "C:\Users\Source\Repos\ETL\ETL.sln" /build Debug
```

**References**

- [/Build (devenv.exe)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/ide/reference/build-devenv-exe?view=vs-2019#example)
- [Devenv command-line switches](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/ide/reference/devenv-command-line-switches?view=vs-2019#devenv-switches)

Comment: After looking thru internet, came to conclusion, there is no direct way to build or automate SSIS project from command line - Is that a fair statement?

Comment: I have tried all above and nothing works, done thru *.bat file with above commands. LMK if i need to do something different.

Comment: This is weird. Check the links i mentioned and you will know that you can automate the build operation.